# nginx - how to functionally achieve an "internal 307 redirect"

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm not sure how to describe the functionality I'm trying to achieve in a way other than "an internal 307 redirect".

Using nginx's `error_page` directive causes nginx to change POST requests to GET requests.
In my config, Nginx proxies requests to some upstream server with `proxy_intercept_errors on` so that I can serve error pages from nginx.

Example:

```
error_page 500 502 503 =500 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /some/document/root/;
}

location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_pass https://somewhere;
}
```

With that config in place, POST requests that result in a 500, 502, or a 503 on the proxy will "secretly" become GET requests to the original URI (/someurl).
Here's a line in the nginx log showing this behavior (I have changed the log format to show $request_method):

```
1.2.3.4 - - [27/Sep/2021:10:04:50 -0400] request_method=GET "POST /someurl HTTP/1.1 500 123 "https://domain.tld/someurl"...
```

You can see that nginx has changed the POST request to a GET request.
(Update: apparently the nginx docs for [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) state exactly that...)

After some research, it seems like this is intentional behavior and is the result of an internal redirect. Apparently the 307 and 308 response codes were created because of similar behavior (albeit on the client, not server).

Is there anything I can do that would have the functionality of an "internal 307 redirect"? i.e., serve an error page but preserve the request method and body? Example, for clarity:

Client POSTs to /someurl, upstream server responds with 500, nginx swallows it and serves "/mygreat500errorpage.html" while preserving the original request method (POST), the original request URI (/someurl) and the original request body.

Update, while still writing this:
I found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1026823/359083) answer that suggests using a named location block to avoid changing the request method. This seems to work with the exception that I can't seem to serve "/mygreat500errorpage.html" from inside the named location. I'm not sure if this is even the correct way of solving the issue, so I'm going to post this question anyways.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. The answer I was going to write would have been identical. Of course you should supply 307 and your own URL.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this question isn't a duplicate because the answer on that question doesn't work, or at least, I don't know how to implement it properly.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about any problems you had implementing it. Please edit your question to provide the relevant details.

Comment: turns out what I wanted to do was effectively allow POST requests to static files which is (understandably) not allowed - ended up writing a webserver to accept POST requests to static files and just proxy error_pages to those using named locations like you would've suggested.